# How to click select drag on a map element using Protractor typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, webautomation

I need help on doing this, i want to click on a particular area, then select drag the area, and then release the click. similar to the image below:

[image: click drag and select]

i tried this code, but nothing happened:

```
browser.actions().
  mouseDown(element(by.id('waze_map1')), '{x: 191, y: 56}').
  mouseMove(element(by.id('waze_map1')), {x: 540, y: 504}).
  mouseUp().
  perform();
```

any suggestion and idea would greatly be appreciated. thanks

Comment: When you say nothing happens do you mean to don't see anything happening on the screen or are you measuring this action another way?

Comment: i mean nothing literally happens, as if it did not perform the action on the screen

Comment: I did need to work with mouse moves before and while it appeared nothing was happening on the screen we had some event listeners which detected that one element was dragged into another box successfully. Is seeing the mouse movement important to the purpose of your test?

Comment: Its not important but i would know that it work, because the item on the map should have change its status as selected, but in my case nothing happen when i run the code above

Comment: Another user recently posted a slightly [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55275737/mouse-actions-not-working-correctly-in-protractor) (but not the same). There approach may help you in this.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues chaining `browser.actions()` which could be what you are running into. Chrome Driver has had issues with this before, although I believe it currently works as intended with current version. I have a similar function in my testing code that does the same thing, the main difference being that I am using async/await. Using your selectors it would look like:

```
await browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id('waze_map1')), '{x: 191, y: 56}').perform(); //moved cursor to starting point
await browser.actions().mouseDown().perform(); //clicks down
await browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id('waze_map1')), {x: 540, y: 504}).perform(); //drags the cursor
await browser.actions().mouseUp().perform();   //releases cursor
```

Comment: `await browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.id('waze_map1')), {x: 191, y: 56}).perform(); //moved cursor to starting point
    await browser.actions().mouseDown().perform(); //clicks down
    await browser.actions().mouseMove().perform(element(by.id('waze_map1')), {x: 540, y: 504}); //drags the cursor
    await browser.actions().mouseUp().perform();   //releases cursor`
error occured in line 3
it prompted an error: _(method) ActionSequence.mouseMove(location: WebElement | ILocation, opt_offset?: ILocation): ActionSequence_

Comment: @SeanRay I accidently put the elementFinder in the perform() and not mouseMove(). I updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at Protractor's documentation [here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions).

This appears to simply inherit from the `Actions` defined by selenium. I am very confused because they give examples using `mouseDown()`, `mouseMove()`, and `mouseUp()`, but looking at the [source code for `Actions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) in selenium, it does not appear to have any method `mouseDown()` or `mouseUp()` nor does it inherit them, unless I am missing something (`mouseMove()` can be found there).

There is, however, a `dragAndDropBy()` method which purports to be "A convenience method that performs click-and-hold at the location of the source element, moves by a given offset, then releases the mouse."  What if you try:

```
browser.actions().dragAndDropBy(yourElement, "540", "504).perform()
```

or

```
browser.actions().dragAndDropBy(yourElement, "540", "504).build().perform()
```

Comment: On the line of code that has`build()` an error occurs, error prompt says _Property 'build' does not exist on type 'ActionSequence'_. While the code that does not have a build() same behavior nothing happens when i ran that code